# What are the spots in my leaves?

Tags: tree-care

It is mid-September update in New York state. The leaves are already falling and have spots on them. Neighbors' trees are still green.

Is it normal? Or my tree is infected with some disease?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are the neighbour's trees that are still green also Maples? Is there anything odd underneath the leaves? I'm seeing skeletonized patches here and there....

Comment: @Bamboo, neighbours' trees are not Maple. Underneath the leaves? There is nothing odd on the ground or on the back side of the individual leaf.

Comment: Perhaps your Maple always starts to show signs of fall before the other trees in the area? There's definitely some fungal leaf spot infection, so just make sure you don't leave any leaves laying on the ground for any length of time, especially not over winter - many fungal spores overwinter in leaf debris.

Answer (score 2):

This is normal.  Deciduous trees are in the process of abscission.  Getting rid of leaves and going dormant.  The spots are fungus, very normal.  When a leaf isn't necessary to the tree the tree cuts it off from supplies such as chemistry and water to make it drop.  This trait for deciduous trees makes them hardier and able to live where there are winters.  The second most vulnerable part of a plant (roots are first) are the leaves. No worries. Do you have a wonderful backpack gas powered blower?  Gotta have one!  Blow leaves into piles or allow them to cover your plant beds, especially where you've got perennials planted.  Great insulation and when the leaves decompose, super for your soil.

It is normal for the same species to be at different phases.  Depends on fertilizer, watering practices and micro climates.